# Directive to allow user to enter number with 2 digit decimal value in angular 4

Tags: angular, directive

I am using below code/directive from plunkr. I need the use to type in numbers with 2 decimals numbers. This below code works fine, but when user starts with a period code breaks and does not allow use to enter a digit before it. Any fix  can do for this or any better way of implementing this. When ever user types in he should be prevented from making mistake.

https://plnkr.co/edit/hyFVKBfksocBXtntC2xx?p=preview

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[OnlyNumber]'
})
export class OnlyNumber {
  elemRef: ElementRef

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.elemRef = el
  }

  @Input() OnlyNumber: boolean;
  @Input() DecimalPlaces: string;
  @Input() minValue: string;
  @Input() maxValue: string;

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;
    if (this.OnlyNumber) {
      if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
          // let it happen, don't do anything
          return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
  }

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
    let e = <any> event

    let valInFloat: number = parseFloat(e.target.value)

    if(this.minValue.length) {
      // (isNaN(valInFloat) && e.key === "0") - When user enters value for first time valInFloat will be NaN, e.key condition is 
      // because I didn't want user to enter anything below 1.
      // NOTE: You might want to remove it if you want to accept 0
      if( valInFloat < parseFloat(this.minValue) || (isNaN(valInFloat) && e.key === "0") ) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    if(this.maxValue.length) {
      if(valInFloat > parseFloat(this.maxValue)) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    if (this.DecimalPlaces) {
      let currentCursorPos: number = -1;    
      if (typeof this.elemRef.nativeElement.selectionStart == "number") {
          currentCursorPos = this.elemRef.nativeElement.selectionStart;
      } else {
        // Probably an old IE browser 
        console.log("This browser doesn't support selectionStart");
      }

      let dotLength: number = e.target.value.replace(/[^\.]/g, '').length
      // If user has not entered a dot(.) e.target.value.split(".")[1] will be undefined
      let decimalLength = e.target.value.split(".")[1] ? e.target.value.split(".")[1].length : 0;

      // (this.DecimalPlaces - 1) because we don't get decimalLength including currently pressed character 
      // currentCursorPos > e.target.value.indexOf(".") because we must allow user's to enter value before dot(.)
      // Checking Backspace etc.. keys because firefox doesn't pressing them while chrome does by default
      if( dotLength > 1 || (dotLength === 1 && e.key === ".") || (decimalLength > (parseInt(this.DecimalPlaces) - 1) && 
        currentCursorPos > e.target.value.indexOf(".")) && ["Backspace", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight"].indexOf(e.key) === -1 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: The field should indicate when it's invalid. If you set the min value to 10 the user won't be able to enter a second digit

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be very close here. It looks like your minValue is causing problems. Specifically the code which is preventing event propagation here:

if( valInFloat < parseFloat(this.minValue) || (isNaN(valInFloat) && e.key === "0") ) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }

You could either remove the criteria to check for the "valInFloat < parseFloat(this.minValue)" portion. Or modify the minValue input (set it to 0.01) which is currently contradictory to starting with a decimal and trying to get two decimal places since currently you have minValue set to 1.0000 in your template.

UPDATE: I partially mis-interpreted your question, I see your concerned with the user being able to add something before the decimal after already starting with a decimal. This will fortunately be a similar fix to the one mentioned above, as it is also due to the logic preventing event propagation once the number specificity condition is met.

UPDATE #2:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[OnlyNumber]'
})
export class OnlyNumber {
  elemRef: ElementRef

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.elemRef = el;
    let periodAllowed: bool = false;
  }

  @Input() OnlyNumber: boolean;
  @Input() DecimalPlaces: string;
  @Input() minValue: string;
  @Input() maxValue: string;


  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;

         console.log('e.target.value:', e.target.value);

    //allow the decimal only when other values are present
    if(e.target.value.length > 0) {
      this.periodAllowed = true;
    } else {
      this.periodAllowed = false;
    }

    if (this.OnlyNumber) {
      if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
         // Allow period
        (e.keyCode == 190 && this.periodAllowed === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
          // let it happen, don't do anything
          return;
       } 

        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
  }

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
    let e = <any> event

    let valInFloat: number = parseFloat(e.target.value)

    if(this.minValue.length) {
      // (isNaN(valInFloat) && e.key === "0") - When user enters value for first time valInFloat will be NaN, e.key condition is 
      // because I didn't want user to enter anything below 1.
      // NOTE: You might want to remove it if you want to accept 0
      if( valInFloat < parseFloat(this.minValue) || (isNaN(valInFloat) && e.key === "0") ) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    if(this.maxValue.length) {
      if(valInFloat > parseFloat(this.maxValue)) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    if (this.DecimalPlaces) {
      let currentCursorPos: number = -1;    
      if (typeof this.elemRef.nativeElement.selectionStart == "number") {
          currentCursorPos = this.elemRef.nativeElement.selectionStart;
      } else {
        // Probably an old IE browser 
        console.log("This browser doesn't support selectionStart");
      }

      let dotLength: number = e.target.value.replace(/[^\.]/g, '').length
      // If user has not entered a dot(.) e.target.value.split(".")[1] will be undefined
      let decimalLength = e.target.value.split(".")[1] ? e.target.value.split(".")[1].length : 0;

      // (this.DecimalPlaces - 1) because we don't get decimalLength including currently pressed character 
      // currentCursorPos > e.target.value.indexOf(".") because we must allow user's to enter value before dot(.)
      // Checking Backspace etc.. keys because firefox doesn't pressing them while chrome does by default
      if( dotLength > 1 || (dotLength === 1 && e.key === ".") || (decimalLength > (parseInt(this.DecimalPlaces) - 1) && 
        currentCursorPos > e.target.value.indexOf(".")) && ["Backspace", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight"].indexOf(e.key) === -1 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

The above is not elegant by any stretch of the imagination, but something like this would accomplish what you've suggested in the comments below.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can i prevent user enter empty period at any time? So that this condition never appears. If he types to enter a period with out any number, prevent default.

Comment: Sure! That would definitely be another option, and might be a better option if it makes sense for your use case. You could use your same RegEx which checks for the location of the period, except now use it to toggle on and off the ability to leverage the keyCode for the period. Similar to how you are doing up top for some of the other keys. Great idea! :)

Comment: I updated the comment above that adds a small update to your snippet which would accomplish what you've suggested.

Comment: I did the same code and came across one more scenario. Say as user i enter few numbers and then i can go back to start and enter a period. Not sure how to prevent it.

Comment: Yes, there will be a range of other scenario's which will have to be identified and handled depending on the expected functionality. For example, we could prevent them from adding a period at the start pretty easily. However this leads to a scenario where say they add it at position 2, but already have a string of 10 characters. Truncating the data may be a bad user experience, ya know? In any case, to handle the case you mentioned, I'd suggest looking at the index of the cursor in relation to the control. If it's position 0, we should prevent that action.

Comment: I added this code to solve the problem. Let me know if code is fine            if(e.key === '.' && (e.target.value.length === 0 ||currentCursorPos === 0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind. Nice work! May be worth updating your question with the resulting code and flagging this one as answered in case it may help someone else dealing with keyCode eventing.

Comment: One last suggestion required. Instead of using e.target.value i can simply use this.elemRef.nativeElement.value right. I feel both are same or any difference ?

Comment: ElementRef API would be the more Angular(ish) way to do it. May also have benefits if you plan on writing unit tests.